# Am I optimizing my wordpress theme too much? Enqueue Style for only a certain page for little CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have been working on optimizing my wordpress theme which I've built, and am wondering if I am optimizing it too much and what are the best practices?

I currently run an if statement and check for a lot of my shop pages with WooCommerce and only Enqueue my shop styles if they are product pages. But my question is how far do I take this?

```
  if(get_the_id() == 2047) {
     wp_enqueue_style ( 'contact-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/contact.css', false, '1.01', 'all'); 
  }
```

For example, I have a contact page with about 50 - 100 lines of CSS, nothing crazy. It currently loads on all my pages. Should I run an if statement in my functions and Enqueue a contact.css style sheet just for that page?

I guess I'm wondering if I'm not dealing with a lot of CSS where it's only 50 - 100 lines, which is slowing down the site more? The if statement in the functions where it checks the page? Or leaving that amount of CSS which is minimized on all my pages even though it's not in use.

Comment: Adding some code could help us help you.

Comment: I just did. Sorry. should have done it from the start.

Comment: There is a trade off between bytes and requests, and there’s no perfect answer. We use a plugin that bundles all CSS together into a single file which means subsequent page requests can use the same cached resource, but we also don’t use CSS frameworks and we’re very light on plugins, so our CSS bundle is relatively smaller. I generally favor increasing bytes over requests, even in an HTTP/2 world, but it is a personal preference. I will say hardcoding IDs into a template will eventually lead to madness, so I’d look for a better way than that at least.

Comment: You might want to do those styles as inline if they're only on one page; rather than adding an extra file download. [wp_add_inline_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say: put it all in the same minified file and focus on targeting your elements correctly with your CSS classes. You can use WebPack or Gulp (my personal favorite) to automate this ;)

You're probably saving like 3 milliseconds of loading time by enqueueing your CSS sheets like this. And you're making your code longer and harder to read. In the end, it's all about making your code easier to maintain on the long run.

Cheers!